Search for Content in a PDF using ifilter on a server running Windows 2022
We have been unable to get content results for PDF files on a new server running Server 2022.  The prior server was 2019 and returned results to the PC clients perfectly.  Search content is enabled and we did install the correct Adobe iFlter.  Seems like there are many similar cases out there.
Installed the correct Adobe ifilter on the W2022 server, configured the extension for properties and content and only properties are returned to the client.  The previous server was running 2019 and work fine.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
